# Enable Google Maps Platform error

Tags: google-maps

For several clients we created websites with a Google Maps included. From July 1st you need an API key to keep those maps working on the website. On https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/ I can create a new API key. But when I enter a **new project name** an click on **next**, I get an error screen, with just an icon with and no additional text, just a **close** button.

I've searched the web and found **Google Cloud Platform** with an error message: *Google Cloud Platform service has been disabled. Please contact your administrator to restore service in G Suite Admin console.* So I've searched de **Admin settings** (I'm an admin) but couldn't find a wrong setting and everything is enabled for API.

Does anyone have a clou where to search or with settings to adjust?

---

UPDATE: I've had contact with Google Support and it was a setting that was disabled. Thats why I couldn't create a project.

GOOGLE ADMIN > APPS > ADDITIONAL GOOGLE SERVICES > **GOOGLE DEVELPERS CONSOLE** (This setting was disabled and when enabled I was allowed to create a project an later add an billing account)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I even contacted Google support and got a callback from them but they had no idea.
What account are you using? I am using an account that is on the legacy free Google apps platform  (rather than a paid G Suite account). I'm wondering if that is the problem

Answer (score 2):

These are the steps I took to be able to enable billing.

- Login to Google with the sys admin email address of the 'G Suite' account
- Go here https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam/organization 
  click on the identity tab on the left menu. (it created an identity)
- click on the 'IAM' option on the left menu
- Add billing account roles to the sys admin email by clicking on the pencil icon to the right of that user name. (I assume you could probably add another user here from the organisation and assign the billing roles to them instead)
- Go to the Gsuite admin: https://admin.google.com/ and click on 'Apps'
- Then click on 'Additional Google services' and enable 'Google developers console'
- Then go to https://console.cloud.google.com/billing
- select your organization from the 'Select an organization:' dropdown box
- click on the 'add billing account' button in the middle of the screen

I have no idea how many of those steps are necessary, but at the end of it, it let me create a billing account

Comment: I have the same problem, so I need to make a paid G suite account first, like in your first step ?

Comment: @Alexa289 No. If you have a free G suite account then follow my steps. If you DON'T have a  G suite account yet then this thread isn't relevant.

Comment: I did make this work for a free G suite account after spending a hour getting run in circles by Googles bad software.