# Always Failed to create Google Map API key for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-platform

[image]

I am new in using google map, I have tried for a day. but when I try to create google map API key for my android project through web site https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/?apis=maps

then I always failed to create API key like the image below:

[image]

am I do something wrong or it is just temporary problem from google ? or is there any alternative to crate API Key for Android Google Map ?

this error only appear on my specific google account, when switch to other gmail, this error never appear

Answer (score 0):

Did you try these steps?

- Login to Google with the sys admin email address of the 'G Suite'
  account
- Go here https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam/organization
  click on the identity tab on the left menu. (it created an identity)
- click on the 'IAM' option on the left menu
- Add billing account roles to the sys admin email by clicking on the
  pencil icon to the right of that user name. (I assume you could
  probably add another user here from the organisation and assign the
  billing roles to them instead)
- Go to the Gsuite admin: https://admin.google.com/ and click on 'Apps'
- Then click on 'Additional Google services' and enable 'Google
  developers console'
- Then go to https://console.cloud.google.com/billing select your
  organization from the 'Select an organization:' dropdown box
- click on the 'add billing account' button in the middle of the screen

from 
[Enable Google Maps Platform error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50794859/enable-google-maps-platform-error)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been recognized in Google Maps Issue tracker and has been addressed. If you are still having issues with this concern, kindly star the [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/123918644) and add a comment of the issue that you are experiencing with replication step as well.

Answer (score 0):

It could have been something temporary. Do you get the same error now, when trying to follow the Get Started URL? https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/?apis=maps

If so, a couple things to check:

1. Are you really logged in with a valid Google account when accessing this page? (since you mention a "specific google account", I assume this is not your issue here)
2. Are you maybe using a G Suite domain account, on which Google Developers Console access has been disabled?

1) If you are not logged in with a valid Google account, you will get this error. You can create a new non-gmail.com Google account on the following page:
https://accounts.google.com/signup/v2/webcreateaccount?hl=en-GB&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=SignUp&nogm=true

2) If you are logged in with a valid Google account, is that a G Suite account? If so, maybe the error happens because your domain admin disabled Google Developers Console access on your account. If so, here is how an admin can re-enable this service: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45621397/11316072.

Note: when the Get Started button doesn't work, you can go to the Google Developers Console directly to create a new project (https://console.cloud.google.com/project), create an API key ((https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=), enable the APIs you need (https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library?project=), and enable billing on your project (https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/linkedaccount?project=).